# Construction of a context free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages, context-free-language

So, I have this language `L={a^i b^2j+1 / i<>j}` and I have to generate a context free grammar based on it, can you please help me in illustrating the steps in doing that.

So far I have this:

```
    S-->aS/aBbb
    B-->bB/b/e(empty)
```

but I am not sure if it is correct, please help me understand it.

Comment: Your grammar accepts `abbb` which has i == j == 1, violating the constraint (S->aBbb, B->b)

Comment: so what would be a correct grammar for that language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For languages with a "not-equal" restriction, the easiest approach is usually to first find a grammar that corresponds to the language with an "equal" restriction instead, and then change it to require more of one of the things.

In this case we have a number of `a` tokens followed by an odd number of `b` tokens where the constraint is on the number of each.  For the equal case, that becomes just

S → aSbb | b

a single `b` with the same number of `a`s and pairs of `b`s wrapped around it.

To make it not-equal, we need to add either extra `a`s or extra pairs of `B`s, but not both:

S → AS' | S'B
S' → aS'bb | b
A → Aa | a
B → Bbb | bb